# Why does setting overflow on a positioned ancestor affect its relative positioned child's position?

Tags: html, css, position

A relative positioned element is relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. What I cannot find documentation on, is why when this parent has its overflow set to a value other than "visible", the positioning of its relative positioned child seems to be affected.

I've reproduced this here, try uncommenting line 12:

```css
html {
  /* this is required to reproduce the issue */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: hotpink;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;

  /* UNCOMMENT LINE 12 AND #APP WILL DISAPPEAR. WHY? */
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
}

#app {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100vw - 20px);
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      Uncomment line #12 and I will disappear. Why?
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the exact same snippet but with line 12 re-enabled:

```css
html {
  /* this is required to reproduce the issue */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

body {
  background-color: hotpink;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;

  /* UNCOMMENT LINE 12 AND #APP WILL DISAPPEAR. WHY? */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#app {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100vw - 20px);
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      Uncomment line #12 and I will disappear. Why?
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a code sandbox so you can play around with it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-cherry-pce0t?file=/src/styles.css

And I've created a screen recording here: https://app.usebubbles.com/dtb9vyNadHq8eMm2YsbfAQ/comments-on-codesandbox-io/

I know that a sticky positioned element is sticky to the nearest ancestor with a scrolling mechanism, which is defined as an element with overflow set to a value other than "visible". I wonder if this is somehow related.

Why does setting overflow on a positioned ancestor affect its relative positioned child's position? I.e. why does #app disappear in the above snippet when line 12 is re-enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. you did not specify height for `body` element. As the `#app` has `position: absolute` the, the parent has no defined and no relative element the parent element collapses and attains height 0.

And also, as the `body` has no height you cannot overflow it. You can only use `#app` to scroll the contents of it overflows.

```css
html {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
body {
  background-color: hotpink;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  width: calc(100vw - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
}

#app {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      This paragraph will overflow in y direction once text fills the container.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So basically you're saying it's because the body is hiding all overflow since it has no height. So why would this render then? It has no height and the overflow is set to hidden: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-shape-g3o7j?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: When you are not using ```overflow-y: hidden``` the CSS sends the overflow property to **default** which is ```overflow: visible```, it still has the *height property 0* but it shows the ```#app``` because *all overflows are visible*.
But when you are using ```overflow-y: hidden``` it hides any contents overflowing in horizontally. So as the body has height 0, and there is no relative elements, no content is visible.
To check it just put ```height: 50px``` in body in your previous code, you will see what I mean.

Comment: I've set `overflow-y: hidden;` on line 12, yet it is still visible. How do you explain that?

Comment: Really? are you talking about ```body``` or ```#app```. If you are really set ```overflow-y: hidden``` in line 12 of your old code and did not change anything at all, the ```#app``` must not be visible but the background of ```body``` should be visible.